# Unable to take input from user in python

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

I have a made a function in which I am taking value from user and want to send that value to another function for verification. But the problem is that I am unable to take value from user because that part of code is not running. The interpreter takes me directly to else part of the while loop. Here is my code:

```
from userAccountDatabase import *
FirstName = ""
LastName = ""
dateOfBirth = ""
userDetails = []

def userDetailsValidation(fieldvalue, fieldName, database):
    for entry in database:
        if fieldName in entry and entry[fieldName] == fieldvalue:
            print("correct value")
            return True
        else:
            return False

def userInputs(FirstName, LastName, dateOfBirth):
    FirstName = str(input("Enter First Name").upper()) # This part of code is not running

    while True:
        if(userDetailsValidation(FirstName, "FirstName", userAccountDetails)) == True:
            userDetails.append(FirstName)
            break
            # directly take me to this
        else:
            print('Enter valid First Name')
            FirstName = str(input("Enter First Name").upper())

userInputs(FirstName, LastName, dateOfBirth)
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please?

Comment: Please reformatt code.

Comment: Indentation matters in Python. Code with incorrect indentation cannot be run. If readers have to try and guess your actual indentation, they may miss problems or introduce new ones into the program. [Edit] your question and reproduce your indentation accurately.

Comment: I have done proper identation at my pc while writing code, but when I copy paste my code here, its identation was disrupted was disrupted when I pressed ctrl+k

Comment: Why do you have two `def userInputs(FirstName, LastName, dateOfBirth):`

Comment: In the first one, I am calling the function userInputs and passing arguments. In the second one I have defined the function userInputs.

Comment: I'm not talking about your userInputs call, I'm talking about the 1st and 16th line of your code, where you have both `def userInputs(FirstName, LastName, dateOfBirth):`. The last line is the function call, I'm not talking about this one.

Comment: It was copy paste by mistake, Please ignore that.

Comment: Why do you say that your code goes inside the `while True` loop ? I don't see any reason your code would do this. Can you add a `print('inside while true loop')` above your `if` inside your loop ? As a side note, consider renaming your parameter, there is a confusion between your parameter name and your global variable FirstName.

Comment: I did everything, Actually due to some wrong identation, Some part of my code was not working. I am new to python and did lots of code editing which leads to the wrong identation. I am finding difficult to properly ident my code.